# Replace properties in jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Springboot and would like to replace the property values in the org.apache.catalina.util ServerInfo.properties file when building the project.  The file is buried in a dependent jar:  tomcat-embed-core-8.5.2.3.jar.  So my app jar will have the replaced values but the tomcat-embed-core-8.5.2.3.jar in the repos will remain as is.

I looked at Maven filters but that looks like it only works if the property file is reachable within my project only (like in src/main/resources), not if the file is in another jar.  Is that right?

What's the best way to do this?  A Maven solution or something simpler is okay.

Comment: ...Why do you want to do this?  This sounds ***incredibly*** dangerous and is likely not at all what you want to do.  Those files contain Tomcat version metadata.  What are you trying to bypass by overriding those properties?

Comment: What *specifically* do you want to change, and why? If it's just server config stuff I'm pretty sure there's a way to do that w/o decimating a third-party jar.

Comment: @DaveNewton:  In Spring Boot there's an embedded Tomcat instance contained within.  I honestly can't think of any reason to mutilate any values in that properties file without there being something incredibly nefarious going on.

Comment: That's what I mean--if it's just config options isn't there a way to tell your embedded Tomcat how you want it to run?

Comment: Under the CIS Tomcat benchmark it is recommended to remove or obfuscate the info in that file to make it harder for hackers to know what container they're dealing with.